# Does "Set-Content" in PowerShell keep the File Access rights?

Tags: powershell, acl, access-rights

I plan to update some files via PowerShell. Will Set-Content keep the access rights (ACL) or do I have to backup and restore these rights explicitly?

Comment: Have you.. tried?

Comment: `Set-Content` does not change file ACLs just contents. Why do you think it might?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried. Because, at the time, I was not able to test it on the files I needed to it, because I wrote the script for my colleague, as I had not the right myself to change the files. I thought I ask, because someone probably already knew the answer. Also it was important, that the ACLs were not changed, So I asked beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Set-Content` (and `Add-Content`) and `Out-File` / `>` (`>>`)** do not *recreate* an existing target file, they *replace (append to) its contents*, so its **ACLs are preserved**.

You can verify this with the following example code:

```
Push-Location $env:TEMP

Remove-Item tmp.txt -EA SilentlyContinue

# Create file 'tmp.txt with default ACL.
'original content' | Set-Content tmp.txt

# Modify the ACL to allow the Guests groups read access.
$acl = Get-Acl tmp.txt
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule Guests, Read, Allow))
Set-Acl tmp.txt $acl

'ACL *before* Set-Content:'
(Get-Acl tmp.txt).Access.IdentityReference | Out-Host


# Use Set-Content to replace the existing content.
'new content' | Set-Content tmp.txt

# Verify that the file's ACL hasn't changed.
'ACL *after* Set-Content:'
(Get-Acl tmp.txt).Access.IdentityReference | Out-Host

Remove-Item tmp.txt
```

The above yields something like the following, showing that the custom ACL was preserved even after replacing the file's content with `Set-Content`:

```
ACL *before* Set-Content:

Value
-----
BUILTIN\Guests
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
BUILTIN\Administrators
WS1\jdoe


ACL *after* Set-Content:

Value
-----
BUILTIN\Guests
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
BUILTIN\Administrators
WS1\jdoe
```